# Удаление неактивных пользователей на Ajax

Tags: ajax, php

Доброй ночи ХешКод, тут возникла большая трудность, делаю чат на Ajax и у меня должны удалятся те кто не был активен в течении 5 минут, вот php код.

```
$date = strtotime("+5 minutes");
mysql_query("DELETE FROM tb_online WHERE date < $date");
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_online WHERE id_session = '$id_session'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
            mysql_query("UPDATE tb_online SET date = '" .time() ."' WHERE id_session = '$id_session'");
        }else{
            if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
                $username = $_SESSION["username"];
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_online(id_session, username,date)VALUES('$id_session', '$username','" .time() ."');") or die(mysql_error());
            }else{
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_online(id_session, username,date)VALUES('$id_session', 'Гость','" .time() ."');") or die(mysql_error());
            }
        }
```

Вот Ajax код:

```
function getOnline(){
    $.post("data.php", {data:"get"}, function(text){
        $("#user").html(text);
        setTimeout(getOnline(), 1000);
    });
}
```

У меня почему-то удаляются постоянно и заново вносятся(мигают постоянно), почему они удаляются если в коде вроде правильно, надо удалять не сразу, а если 5 минут не был активен? В чём проблема?

Answer (score 2):

а что вы хотите? у вас клиент получает данные и вставляет их в нужное место $("#user").html(text);.Поэтому они сначала удалятся а потом появятся

Елиже вы хотите реально сделать что добавляись только новые пользователи и удалялись неактивные, то вам а клиенте нада хранить список активных в массиве. когда получаете с сервера список, то сравниваете 2 массива, если юзер ущел  то удаляете егомз массива и из представления, если юзер пришел, добавляете его в массив и в представление.

Также совет по серверной части- перепишите ее с использованием кеширования. Можно самому написать. Принцип следующий-список ативных пользователей берется не и базы а из подготовленного файла, также в ем указывается метка создания, а клиенты на запрос шлют также метку предыдущего полученного файла - если метки совпадаю т то и отсылать ничего не нада - но тут опятьже на клиенте доработка нужна. А вот сам файл перезаписывается от действий в базе - юзер пришел - файлик перезаписали, юзер ушел - файлик перезаписали.

Answer (score 0):

Может что то неправильно со временем.. просмотри переменные. Возможно у тебя ошибка в числах.